# Loop to fill class properties?

Tags: c#, class, oop, properties

Let's say I have a Class Person with a bunch of properties (FirstName, LastName, Address, City, etc)

I am pulling data to fill these properties from an Excel file (using the excellent EPPlus library) where each of the columns are identical to the Person properties, in the same order.

Is there a way to iterate through all the properties in Class Person to fill them?

Currently I am doing this:

```
person.FirstName= worksheet.Cells[2, 1].Text;
person.LastName= worksheet.Cells[2, 2].Text;
person.Address= worksheet.Cells[2, 3].Text;
person.City= worksheet.Cells[2, 4].Text;
person.Age= worksheet.Cells[2, 5].Text;
//repeat for a dozen more properties
```

This seems rather inelegant. Is there some loop I can use?

Comment: Does the Cells collection contain a value that maps back to the property? Like does `Cells[1, 1]` equal "FirstName"? If so, then yes you can use reflection to iterate over the collection and map them back to properties on the object

Comment: Cells[1, X] are the column names (in EEPlus library, it actually looks like cells[y, x]). They are in the same order horizontally as my class properties are vertically. My properties names do not match the column names exactly (naming conventions and such).

I do not have any experience with reflections. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: There are numerous examples of how to use reflection, on MSDN and here on Stack Overflow. See e.g. the `Type.GetProperties()` method. But note that especially without an exact correspondence between the input data and class property names, this isn't likely to be simple to implement. If you try using reflection and have trouble, then please ask a question showing exactly what you've actually tried and including a clear, specific explanation of what you're having trouble with.

Comment: It will be faster for you to hard-code the 17 properties to a specific column number, plus you'll maintain type safety, which you'll lose with reflection.  The only reason I would consider reflection is if the number and.or order of columns could change in the source file.

Comment: Since your column names and properties name do not match, you would have to create an attribute that would be applied to each property to handle the mapping of property names to column names, then write the reflection code. The reflection solution would be far less 'elegant' than what you are currently doing. You would also take a substantial (relative) hit in performance. By the time you did all that, as mentioned by @DStanley, you'd be done writing your manual mapping of properties and off coding other things.

Comment: Indeed after looking at it, hard-coding the properties appears to be the way to go. Thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest impediment here is the question of how you would automatically associate your column index to a specific property. I.e. how is the code supposed to know that column index `1` corresponds to the `FirstName` property.

It is possible to retrieve a list of `PropertyInfo` objects from your class's type. These objects can be used with an instance of your class to set or get property values. So assuming you have some way to map a column index to a specific property, and thus to a specific `PropertyInfo` object, you could order the list of `PropertyInfo` objects in such a way that you use the same index as for the column (or more likely, the column index minus one).

But reflection is slow and, frankly, can be confusing and difficult to use, especially for non-experts. It is also difficult to get reflection to perform well, speed-wise.

Personally, I would stick to what you have already. I.e. explicitly write the appropriate assignment for the appropriate index. The one modification I'd make is instead of using literals in the code, define `const` values. E.g.:

```
const int firstNameColumn = 1;
const int lastNameColumn = 2;
// etc.

void InitializeFromCell(Worksheet worksheet, int rowIndex)
{
    person.FirstName = worksheet.Cells[rowIndex, firstNameColumn].Text;
    person.LastName = worksheet.Cells[rowIndex, lastNameColumn].Text;
    // etc.
}
```

You might consider abstracting the mapping from column to property in a separate method, so that at least you only have to write the code once:

```
void SetIndexedProperty(Person person, int propertyIndex, string value)
{
    switch (propertyIndex)
    {
    case firstNameColumn:
        person.FirstName = value;
        break;
    case lastNameColumn:
        person.LastName = value;
        break;
    // etc.
    }
}

void InitializeFromCell(Worksheet worksheet, int rowIndex)
{
    for (int columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= numberOfColumns; columnIndex++)
    {
        SetIndexedProperty(person, columnIndex, worksheet.Cells[rowIndex, columnIndex].Text);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could abstract the assignment using an array of `Action<Person, string>` delegates:

```
static readonly Action<Person, string>[] _propertyIndexers =
{
    (person, value) => person.FirstName = value,
    (person, value) => person.LastName = value,
    // etc.
}

void InitializeFromCell(Worksheet worksheet, int rowIndex)
{
    for (int columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= numberOfColumns; columnIndex++)
    {
        _propertyIndexers[columnIndex - 1](person, worksheet.Cells[rowIndex, columnIndex].Text);
    }
}
```

IMHO, any of the above would be a simpler, easier-to-understand approach than reflection. This would be true even if you had an exact one-for-one correspondence between the worksheet data's column name and your actual property name, and lacking that, it's even more true. :)

Comment: Thanks for the thorough tips. I very much like the idea of using const values for code readability